# Show effort and *all* clocked time for completed tasks within the last week

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

How can I show all the time spent on org-mode tasks completed within the last
week?

The `clocktable` doesn't include time logged outside the
`block` time.  For a task that's spread over many weeks, the total time is
misleadingly low.

If I make the block time larger, e.g. a month, I get too many tasks and I'm
still not guaranteed to show all the time spent on completed tasks.

In the example below, *Task with work from more than a week ago* doesn't include
the hour logged on December 2nd.

```
* DONE Task with work from more than a week ago
  CLOSED: [2016-12-12 Mon 22:47]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Effort:   0:30
  :END:
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2016-12-02 Fri 21:49]--[2016-12-02 Fri 22:49] =>  1:00
  CLOCK: [2016-12-12 Mon 22:14]--[2016-12-12 Mon 22:47] =>  0:33
  :END:
** TODO Subtask 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Effort:   0:10
  :END:
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2016-12-12 Mon 21:37]--[2016-12-12 Mon 21:47] =>  0:10
  :END:
* DONE Task with all time within a week
  CLOSED: [2016-12-12 Mon 22:47]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Effort:   0:05
  :END:
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2016-12-12 Mon 23:38]--[2016-12-12 Mon 23:48] =>  0:10
  :END:


#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 9 :scope file :block thisweek :fileskip0 t :tcolumns 1 :properties ("effort")
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2016-12-12 Mon 22:49], for week 2016-W50.
| effort | Headline           |   Time |
|--------+--------------------+--------|
|        | *Total time*       | *0:53* |
|--------+--------------------+--------|
|   0:30 | DONE Task 1        |   0:43 |
|   0:10 | \_  TODO Subtask 1 |   0:10 |
|   0:05 | DONE Task 2        |   0:10 |
#+END
```